# TFS 2010 Build get part of workspace based on a label

Tags: build-automation

I've got an automated build in TFS 2010 with the following workspace:

```
$/Program 1   $(SourceDir)\Program 1
$/Core        $(SourceDir)\Core
```

I then build both the core projects and the program 1 specific projects as part of the build. However, in doing bug fixes for a previous version, I need to get a specific label of the core files, but the latest for program 1 files. How can I change the workspace for only the Core directory to get by the label instead of getting the latest.

I know I can create a branch from the label for the Core folder, but since the bug fix is only in the Program 1 files, I don't want to create a new branch that has no changes in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an Solution that imports code from different TeamProjects.
 That's not quite an optimum setup, one more flexible alternative could be the following:

```
$/Program1
    /SharedSources
       /Core_branch
          Core.csproj
    /Sources
       /Program1
          Program1.csproj
       /Program2
          Program2.csproj
       Sources.sln
```

If you had setup your SCM-structure like that, you would just have to define the following in your build definition:
 `$/Program1    $(SourceDir)`

So, if you had an issue on a past version of `Program1`, you could proceed with a Hotfix branch and not face your current challenge . An excellent resource on general TFS branching & solution shaping in source control can be found [here](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).

On your specific question "How can I change the workspace for only the Core directory to get by the label instead of getting the latest.":
In you own Workstation/Workspace, you could get a past version & then use [Cloak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181378%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to exclude `Core` from a following GetLatest. This can enable you to conduct analysis, even create shelvesets containing changes within `Program1` that fix any bugs.
But, since cloaking isn't usable during build (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042876/tfs-2010-cloaking-in-the-build-definition-file-error) for an interesting post), I believe you are eventually forced to proceed with a branch, in order to get your fixes build.

Comment: I agree that the solution layout isn't ideal. However, we also don't necessarily want a branch for every program; most programs use the same core version. Thanks for the links to the branching document, I'll read over them for future improvements to our folder layout.